# Configure IPTables on KVM host to drop packets on the virtual isolated network

Tags: networking, iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have two KVM guests, both connected to a KVM virtual isolated network (called `virbr1`, address space `10.0.0.0/24`). For testing a routing solution, I want to imitate a failure of the physical link between the guests. To do that, I insert iptables rule at the **KVM host**:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

But it does not block the traffic. `tcpdump` on the host still shows packets in the 10.0.0.0/24 network.

My next attempt was to drop all packets to the virtual bridge:

```
iptables -m physdev -A OUTPUT --physdev-in virbr1 -j DROP
```

But the guests continue to exchange the packets, and `tcpdump -i virbr1` on the host shows that traffic.

Why is it not dropped by the host?

Overall, is this a proper solution for testing physical link failure?

Comment: Two reasons come to mind: 1) The order of rules matters and using `-A` to append new often results in a previous rule matching and negating that new rule. Debug with `iptables -L -n -v`  - 2) The OUTPUT chain may not be the appropriate chain and your rule should have more effect in POSTROUTING (the hypervisor is routing packets for the KVM guests and not the source)

Comment: How exactly is `virbr1` a **physical** device (`--physdev-in virbr1`)?  In any case, even if the rules are working, tcpdump on the INPUT interface will still show the traffic.  In any any case, this isn't a good solution for testing physical link failure - unplugging a cable will work much better.  If there isn't one, **it is meaningless to talk about physical link failure**.  In short, your question appears very confused to me, possibly fatally so.

Comment: @MadHatter: I believe it is not meaningless at all to talk about physical link failure. I want to test the behavior of the hosts in this case. Testing with unplugging real network cable is undoubtedly the best and the only 100% accurate. But before I arrange extra hardware (and before I transfer the software from the development environment to that setup and go unplugging cables), I want to do the initial check - what happens if the IP packets are not received by the peer.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but **if there is no physical link, it cannot fail**.  You can only do something that you believe models that reasonably closely - what they call in evidence-based medicine *a surrogate outcome* - so why not just `iptables -I INPUT 1 -i virbr1 -j DROP` on each guest?

Comment: @MadHatter: *why not just iptables -I INPUT 1 -i virbr1 -j DROP on each guest?* - because the guests are running operating system, which has nothing similar to `iptables`, and is not capable of much IP manipulation at all :)

Comment: Fair enough, though you might have mentioned that in your question rather than making us dig it out of you.  In any case, I think HBruijn has hit the nail on the head in his answer - if you've virtualised the network, use the same approach to virtualise the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the state of the network link for a KVM guest it would be much better to use the appropriate tool, i.e. the hypervisor

```
virsh domif-setlink domain interface-device state
```

> Modify link state of the domain’s virtual interface. Possible values
>   for state are **"up"** and **"down"**. If `--config` is specified, only the
>   persistent configuration of the domain is modified, for compatibility
>   purposes, `--persistent` is alias of `--config`.  interface-device can
>   be the interface’s target name or the MAC address.

Comment: Much better, yaaay HBruijn, as usual!